# CakePHP (or just PHP) get session duration

Tags: php, cakephp, session-timeout

Is there any way to get the duration of the user's session?

If the user logs in I can save the initial time. If he logs out, I can get the final time and calculate the duration of the session.

What if the user doesn't log out and the session just expires? Is there any way to know if/when that happens?

Comment: "Is there any way to know if/when that happens?" --- if only you have a custom sessions handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to know if the session is still active, so the best thing you can do is save the `SESSION_START_TIME` on you Database and on every request log a `LAST_REQUEST_TIME`.

that way you know when was the start and the "possible" end of the session.

you can also know how many active sessions there are right now, by checking all sessions with `LAST_REQUEST_TIME<5minutes`... so its not a bad solution.

Comment: +1 I was just going to post the same answer. I would recommend storing all times in a Unix timestamp format by using time(). This makes it way easier to do calculations with php.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really.  HTTP is session less.  People who really want a more granular idea of active users will frequently use some sort of heartbeat technology, that creates a persistent connection or simulates it with polling, using ajax, or a flash movie, or websockets.

PHP sessions are really more of a mechanic for linking some temporary serverside storage with a specific client/browser instance, despite the implication some might read into the name.